# Invoke Excel Ribbon button for an installed ExcelDna AddIn as part of an integration test

Tags: c#, excel, office365, vsto, excel-dna

I am attempting to create integration tests for an Excel Addin developed using ExcelDna and VSTO automation.  I would like to test different functions of our application but need to utilize the CommandBar for our addins commandbar.

I am attempting to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference and the RegisterXLL method to register the XLL within Excel.

I am attempting to create the tests on a Windows 10 box with Office 365 installed.

There are several issues that I am having that there is are many potentially outdated posts on.

Initially, I instantiated the Excel application, registered the addin, and attempted to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.SendKeys to send keystrokes to the instance of Excel. While I was initially able to get this to work while debugging the test with breakpoints, it does not work while running tests. There are multiple posts that indicate that on Windows 10, Office is now a universal application and that SendKeys will no longer work as it violates UAC and the Win32 API calls to send keys to an application similarly do not work since Office is a universal application.

My second attempt is to attempt to invoke the Commandbar and its menu items via VSTO automation code and I cannot seem to find any posts that indicate how to invoke commandbar functions in a different application domain.

Additionally, when I close the Excel instance I notice that there is always a process of Excel running even though the code below is being used to kill the excel application.

```
    void CloseApp()
    {
        xlApp.Quit();
        xlApp = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

I am at the point of confusion on how this would be accomplished. Does anyone have any posts that they can point to that resolve these issues that still work?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the closing, you might want to split the code with COM calls from the GC calls, to ensure that the debugger does not keep the local variables alive (and prevent the GC from running and releasing the COM objects. So you want to follow this pattern:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace TestCsCom
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // NOTE: Don't call Excel objects in here... 
            //       Debugger would keep alive until end, preventing GC cleanup

            // Call a separate function that talks to Excel
            DoTheWork();

            // Now let the GC clean up (repeat, until no more)
            do
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
            while (Marshal.AreComObjectsAvailableForCleanup());
        }

        static void DoTheWork()
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Add();
            Worksheet worksheet = book.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
            app.Visible = true;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                worksheet.Cells.Range["A" + i].Value = "Hello";
            }
            book.Save();
            book.Close();
            app.Quit();

            // NOTE: No calls the Marshal.ReleaseComObject() are ever needed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Govert. I restructured to have setup and teardown methods and handle the instantiation and disposal separately. This eliminates the ghosting issue that I was encountering. Now I just need a way to go across domains from the instantiated interop to call a ribbon button in Excel that is part of a registered XLL.